# Text Formatting is changed while Sharing data: Android

Tags: java, android, plaintext

I want to share diamond detail in table format(Plain text not `HTML`)

I have made this using this [library](https://github.com/thedathoudarya/WAGU-data-in-table-view) but its prints the data properly using the system.out but while I sharing it, its format is changed:
[image]

Below is my code:

```
  List<String> headersList = Arrays.asList("", "");
                    List<List<String>> rowsList = Arrays.asList(
                            Arrays.asList("Stone Id :", details[0]),
                            Arrays.asList("Lab", details[1]),
                            Arrays.asList("Shape", details[2]),
                            Arrays.asList("Carat", details[3]),
                            Arrays.asList("Clarity-Color", details[4]),
                            Arrays.asList("Cut-Pol-Sym-Flou", details[5]));


                    Board board = new Board(75);
                    Table table = new Table(board, 75, headersList, rowsList);
                    table.invalidate().setGridMode(Table.GRID_NON).setRowsList(rowsList);
                    List<Integer> colWidthsList = Arrays.asList(30, 14);
                    table.setColWidthsList(colWidthsList);
                    Block tableBlock = table.tableToBlocks();
                    board.setInitialBlock(tableBlock);
                    board.build();
                    String preview1 = board.getPreview();
                    System.out.print(preview1);
                    sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,preview1);
```

Comment: The screenshot contains sharing on whatsapp?

Comment: yes. but same problem with other apps as well

Comment: I think because of max-width of the row of whatsapp and other apps is smaller than the length of the text you are sharing. Try with some small text Like only with stoneid and Lab and see if this behavior is persistent or not

Comment: just tried but the same issue. Also checked with landscape mode but still problem

Comment: Exporting text-formatted table is useless, unless you can't control the font. Console output is fixed-width font, but WatsApp used regular one. Use tabs for formatting, but there also no guarantee about formatting on receiver's side.

Answer (score 1):

The console uses monospaced font which takes exactly same width for all characters. But your view isn't using it, so it looks messed up.

Use a monospaced font.

Or use a tabular format. Perhaps a ListView with each row having two text views side by side having fixed width.

Comment: use something like ListView

Comment: monospaced is right. I just checked it's working with paint. How can I set with shared text?

Comment: what do you mean by shared text?

Comment: Text is text, the render decides the font, unless you "markup" the text with something like HTML.

Comment: I want to share this tabular text to another apps (like whatsapp, wechat etc) as well using intent.